# List opengl extensions USED in runtime

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

How I can get a list with openGl extensions that I am used in my program at runtime in C++. Clarifying, I don't want extensions available in my platform, I don't want extensions I can execute, I want a list of extensions I am using in my code. This is to check if this extensions are availables before start the execution. I am looking GLEW but GLEW is for

> determining which OpenGL extensions are supported on the target platform.

And what I want is a way to get what extensions I am using. If anyone knows not runtime way please tell me because maybe is useful too.

Also, I want tho know how to determine minimum opengl version to use.

Comment: No, there is no standard, fool-proof way to do that. But let me ask you this: if *you* don't know what extensions you are using, then who does?!

Answer (score 0):

Actually [the standard way](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/extensions.php) to handle extensions is *in-situ*: test for availability before trying to call it.

```
if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_program) 
{ 
  ...  // Do something with ARB_vertex_program
}
```

More complexes OpenGl programs will perform tests on several extensions availability and make decision from that:

```
if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_array_object && other stuff)
{
   renderingTechnic = VERTEX;
}
else
{
   renderingTechnic = BEGIN_END;
}

... etc
```

If you want the list of actually used extension it's become tricky.

You have to detect cases like this:

```
if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_program && 0) // YOU SHALL NOT PASS
{ 
  ...  // Do something with ARB_vertex_program
}
```

In this case, you will never enter in the *then-statement* but your tool may have difficulty to detect it.

[Code coverage tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) are here to perform this kind of job, but embed ones to perform the comparison with available extension at runtime  is not an option here.

Take a look in the [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) of your output is neither a solution:

- The one for you exe will contain none of OpenGl functions.
- The one for the OpenGl library will contain all of possible (not **available** nether **used**) functions.

Comment: Actually, the symbol table from the OpenGL library might contain much more than the available extensions (or maybe none of them.) An OpenGL library most likely supports more than a single specific hardware, so even an OpenGL implementation (that relies on hardware) needs to detect what is and what is not supported at runtime.

Comment: @yzt, thanks for your remark, I tried to include it.

Comment: So there is no way to test all extensions at one time? I mean, check if platform have ext1, ext2, ... in the same function, before use it.

Comment: You test it like this `if (GLEW_ext1 && GLEW_ext2 && ...)` the idea is to make the decision of what you will do at runtime (because you only know at runtime which extension are present). The final response is: it's your job to list the ext you need at init so you can decide if you can run your program or not (and of course you can use different algorithm depending on what is available).

Comment: @Orace Is what I imagined, but the problem is I can't use GLEW and my program use a lot of extensions. Will be a tedious task

Answer (score 0):

If your codebase is anything but humongous, you can simply do this with a bit of searching for "gl_EXT_", "gl_ARB_", etc. and manual inspection and a dash of discipline afterwards to try and document all the extensions you use.

For minimum version; again, this is something pretty basic that you need to know already when writing the code. But here I think using GLEW can help you. If memory serves, GLEW uses preprocessor macros that you can define to set the version of OpenGL standard you are expecting. You start by setting this to a low value (e.g. 1.1) and see if your code compiles and runs. If it does, that's probably the minimum version you need. If it doesn't, you increment the version and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to decide which extensions you're going to use *before* you're starting the actual coding. And if you change it later on, you immediately put the availability tests somewhere close to initialization so that you can either terminate with a runtime error message or fall back to an alternate code path.

Of course the preferred way is to not use *extensions* at all and stick to a plain OpenGL version profile. Yes, anything after OpenGL-1.2 is loaded through the extension mechanism, but that doesn't make it extensions. So if you know you absolutely need OpenGL-3.0 for your program to work, but nothing else then you can just test for that and be done.